# The content of a variable of many forms with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Any suggestion of how the "old_photo" variable could be specific name?

When this code is processed, the "old_photo" variable is only picked a random file. But, the variable "photo_input" is working fine.

In the HTML generated, all variables are correct, the main problem is in the reception of the "old_photo" variable.

```
// Images directory

 if (is_dir($directorio)) {
     if ($dh = opendir($directorio)) {

         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

             if (strcmp($file, ".") and strcmp($file, "..")) {
                   list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize(getcwd() . $separator . "images" . $separator . $file);
                   echo "<form action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' style='width:150px; height:150px; display:inline;' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' >";
                   echo "<input type='hidden' name='old_photo' value='".$file. "'>";
//echo "<input type='hidden' name='".$file."' value='".$file. "'>";
                   echo "<label for='photo_input'>";
                   echo "<img src='" . basename($directorio) . $separator . $file . "' height='100px' width='100px'/>";
                   echo "</label>";
                   echo "<input type='file' style='display:none;' id='photo_input' name='photo_input'  onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
                   echo "</form>";
               }

           }
           closedir($dh);
      }
}
```

The values are collected by these functions:

```
function test_input($data)
{
     return trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($data)));
}

$cadena = "old_photo";
//$cadena = $value;

$imagen_antigua = test_input(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $cadena));
var_dump($imagen_antigua); // Nunca es correcta
```

Comment: What do you mean by specific values? Is it user input or data stored in database?

Comment: it is an images directory, I want to replace a specific photo, with other photo. The variable "a" is the old photo.

Comment: i have tested with more than 100 and with 10. Is It a limit of storage about the POST variables?

Comment: I would recommend you to loop through the image file. Your image should have a proper naming for organising. Eg. Image_001, Image_002. Assign ID to the images, and when you want to change the photo, you can change the photo id. You will have more control and it is more organised.

Comment: `name='a[]'` - it should be an array of fields.

Comment: Well this line of your code sets the value of a to a file from the directory in a hidden field `"<input type='hidden' name='a' value='".$file. "'>";` if you want it set to something specific then put the value you want in there instead. The upload works because the filename will change when the user chooses an image to upload, but they can't change the value in the hidden field

Comment: The hidden field is the current name of a photo, then, I do not want to users change the hidden value. If I pick up any reference of the old photo, I could change It with the new photo.